# Command Line argument

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm having a very hard time at trying to do trivial things with Visual-generated C++ code.
This is getting frustrating beyond expectation.

I'm accustomed at getting arguments from command line thanks to :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

OK, this works, at least as long as we stay in an ANSI world.

Now, Visual generates this :

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```

I'm somewhat clueless as to how to work with this line.
I've obviously tried to swap the unknown semantic with the more familiar one, but compilation fails. I've also been roaming Internet for an unreasonably large amount of time, finding many examples for this situation, but none of them ever worked...

[Edit] Small explanation on what i'm attempting to do : this is supposed to be a trivial yet a GUI program. It takes a filepath from command line argument, and write in it depending on options selected by the user on the GUI.
So : it is not a CLI, It is a Windows Form.

Comment: Just for your reference, that thing is a handle (something like a "GC managed pointer") to a .NET array of handles to .NET strings, and it contains the arguments given to your application.

Comment: Well, i tried, but this is even worse. There is not even a 'main' function anywhere. Here is what looks closest to a main that i could find :int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)

Comment: @Cyan: This is a Windows subsystem application, and yes, WinMain is the entry point in this case.

Comment: Please note that a console application can create UI windows as well.  That might be the fastest path to success, if you are most familiar with `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: ok, but can i remove the console itself ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a .NET project, and what you're seeing is C++/CLI, not C++. Create a native project (Win32 Application or something like that) instead.

Comment: Ya, Console App is the most likely match.

Comment: Also, you may want to select "Empty project" if you don't want to deal with the `TCHAR` stuff for now.

Comment: I'm supposed to write a GUI. I can't produce a console text-only app.

Comment: @Attract: C++/CLI is the name of the language, the CLI in it doesn't have anything to do with command-line interface. You need to decide whether you want to write native application, or .NET one. You can have GUI in either.

Comment: Well, this is supposed to be a trivial program. I don't mind if it is CLI or not, as long as i can get the command line argument. Everything else seems to look like standard C++. I did nothing specific, just created a "windows form" project with Visual.

Comment: @Attract: I think you missed the point. In C++/CLI, CLI means "Common Language Infrastructure". It is a language based on C++, formerly known as "Managed C++", which has a different syntax than C++. If you want to use this language, you should learn it first, especially the differences to standard C++. Then `array<System::String ^> ^args` won't be so mystical to you. Or (better) for a trivial GUI program, why don't you use just C#, which might be better suited for your needs. If you just know C++, then learning C# won't be harder than learning C++/CLI.

Comment: @DocBrown : i've been able to do a lot of modifications into this C++/CLI program, they all work as intended. I did not notice any difference with standard C++ up to the point of needing to get an argument from command line. I feel like this is the only point missing for me to finish my program. Just telling to "get rid of everything and learn a completely new language or restart the program from scratch", all this due to a simple command line parameter issue.. how come ?

Comment: @Attract: well, C++/CLI should be easy to learn if you already know C++. For example, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx contains a 10 minute introduction. To get the command line args in your example: `args[0], args[1], ...` gives you the arguments, `args->Length` the array size. When you have specfic issues with that, post the exact line of your code, then we can give you specific advice.

Comment: @DocBrown : thanks, this is exactly the information i'm looking for !